# Is webRTC supprted in ios 12 sfsafariviewcontroller?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios12

I'm developing an application and in somewhere in application I need to open to a website in SFSafariViewController and the website needs to access rear camera. It works like a charm in iOS 14 but in iOS 12 the CAMERA permission alert doesn't show up and camera don't work. So I have the question if webRTC supported in iOS 12 SFSafariViewController or not?

Answer (score 0):

most likely not. Check whether `navigator.mediaDevices` and `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` are present. If not getUserMedia is unsupported.